# Receiving data from local Wifi and streaming it to a remote server using 3G in realtime through Android App

Tags: java, android, raspberry-pi, android-wifi, 3g

I am trying to stream ADC data from raspberry pi to a remote server. In-order to provide internet access we are planning to use the 3G internet available in android smartphones.

I have set up a raspberry pi as a Wifi access point. Now the android device can successfully ping the tomcat server which was set up on pi.

Now the challenge is to send this data in real-time to the remote server. Is it possible to use the 3G data available at the smartphone for this? (I have read in another thread that some have connected a wifi printer and used 3G at the same time. But details are very limited.)

All suggestions are appreciated.
(one more thing - connecting pi directly to internet is not feasible here. That is why we are trying smartphones)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear as it sounds like you have a server on the Raspberry Pi as well as a remote server?

If all you want to do it send data from the Raspberry Pi, over WiFi to the phone and then via 3G to the internet and on to your remote sever then, so long as your service provider supports it and does not have extra or prohibitive charges, the standard HotSpot mechanism on most Android phones will do this.

The flow looks like:

Raspberry Pi -> WiFi -> Android Phone acting as Hotspot -> 3G -> Internet -> Remote server

Comment: Thanks Mick. I was suggested  the same in Raspberry pi forums also. The confusion came from a little misunderstanding. The pi while working wont be connected to a monitor. So password and Hotspot name had to be provided in config files of Pi. We now specify a specific hotspot-password combo in pi and use the same credential while creating mobile hotspot